# Trouble Opening External Web-Page

Tags: tidesdk

I'm trying to open an external webpage in a child window using the following code

```
var secondwindow = Ti.UI.createWindow("http://www.google.com");
```

This used to work fine before but suddenly it stopped working, and I also tried to open this using

```
window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
```

but this doesn't work either. The application console output is

[Ti.Network.Analytics][Error] Failed for URL https://api.appcelerator.net/p/v1/app-track: Couldn't connect to server

Can someone explain to me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood (just started learning the SDK) you can't do this. You would define your own window in the app package by writing an html file, would open it by using the Ti.UI object and the get the external HTML content by using the HTTPCLient of the Ti.Network namespace. By that you would load the needed HTML content or other like JSON maybe and implant it into your window HTML DOM.

Example:

First, you would create a new window using you own html file:

```
Ti.UI.createWindow("app://special-window.html")
```

In that file you would execute some Javascript to GET some external resources like HTML:

```
//Request URL
var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/api/users/';
//Create the HTTP Client
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
         //request complete do something with data
         //assuming that we are not working with XML
         Ti.API.INFO('Response received '+this.responseText);
         // DO SOMETHING WITH THE this.responseText HERE (like adding it to your DOM)
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
         //error received, do something
    }
});

//Specify request type and open 
client.open('GET',url);
//Send request
client.send();
```

The code was taken from the docs. (As I said, I am just starting to use the SDK)

Hope, I could help a bit :)